# Pandas Groupby and find duplicates in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and I want to groupby the 'Value_pack' column and check if 2 or more 'Value_pack' have the same 'value' and 'discount'. (Duplicates)

I want to remove all but the first occurrence of duplicates from the dataframe.

Input Dataframe:

```
  Value_pack    value   discount
    val 1        ADA       0
    val 2        ADB       100
    val 2        ADA       0  <---- duplicate
    val 3        ADA       50
    val 3        ADC       50
    val 4        ADV       40
```

Output Dataframe:

```
    Value_pack  value   discount
    val 1        ADA       0
    val 2        ADB       100
    val 3        ADA       50
    val 3        ADC       50
    val 4        ADV       40
```

df.groupby(['Value_pack']).drop_duplicates(['value', 'discount'])

This is the code I have so far but I can't work out how to get the dataframe I want.

Answer (score 2):

Using groupby you need to approach this from the other end: You group by value and discount and pick the first Value_pack:

```
df.groupby(["value", "discount"]).first().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `groupby`. Try: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['value', 'discount'])`. Check out docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html?highlight=drop_duplicates#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

You would not need to do a group by for this, something like this could help :

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['value', 'discount'], keep = 'first')
```